# Search String between two string in different file

Tags: python, regex, string

I am writing a python script and have got stucked at one point.

My objective here is to find or search a string or a expression between two dates/time. I can do this using "sed" but my problem is the start time and the end time can be in two different files.

The thing is that I am generating some logs which are printed in a file with time stamp at every line. If the number of lines reaches a certain limit, we start writing the logs in a different file.

I need to search for a pattern or expression between two dates/time and I am not sure whether it is in the same file or not.

Can anyone suggest me how can I approach this and do it.

Comment: I am writing python script. In which i have currently find the two times between which I want to search for string. The log file are automatically generated and I want to use this script to find if pattern exist in these logfile between two different time.

Comment: That's not code, that's an explanation. People are not here to write the code for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
cat file1 file2 file3 | your_sed_script
```

or simply

```
cat file* | your_sed_script
```

just make sure the files are in alphabetical order (log files identified with `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` and not `MMDDYYYY` or similar).

Comment: its a good option but, to the number of files could be large. The output will be too hard to collect of CAT. I want to use this in a python script.

Comment: `cat` sends lines of all files into the pipe and your sed script processes them also line by line… so they won't be completely copied anywhere and this is as fast as parsing individual files.